# How to split two or more address

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I'm getting data from server side in this format

```
    coll={state:AP,address:['(A14,F4,J.V VILLA(AC))','(A5,F4,Json Park(DC))']}
```

and i want to put address in select box as option

```
    select box
     ----A14,F4,J.V VILLA(AC)
     ----A5,F4,Json Park(DC)
```

what have i tried

```
    jQuery.each(coll,function(key,value){  
       var temp_address=value.address.split(',');
       jQuery.each(temp_address,function(key1,value1){
             var option = new Option(value1, value1);
             select_purchase.append(jQuery(option));
       });
```

I get my output as

```
 select box
 ----(A14,F4,J.V VILLA(AC))
 ----(A5,F4,Json Park(DC))
```

I want to remove those round bracket aeound address, I afraid to use regex because it might remove my round bracket inside address and can anybody help me out with efficient insertion of option in select box from array.I want it because i might have large number of address and this might be slow

**Update**
After googling for sometime i found that traditional forloop is much faster then each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A carefully made regex will only remove the outside parenthesis:

```
var address = address.replace(/^\(|\)$/g,'');
```

This expression can be interpreted like this:

```
 ^ at the start
 \( a parenthesis
 | or
 \) a parenthesis
 $ at the end
```

The matching strings are replaced with `''`.

You can call it like this:

```
coll.address = coll.address.map(function(s){ return s.replace(/^\(|\)$/g,'') });
```

Note that if you always want to remove the first and last character, you can also simply do

```
var address = address.slice(1,-1);
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it might be more helpful if you would explain that

Comment: @BalkrishnaPathak I edited to explain. Is it clear ?

Comment: thanks for explaining it was very much clear, is the way of inserting option into selectbox from an array is efficient please help me with that

Comment: i get error as coll.address.map is not a function on console

Comment: @BalkrishnaPathak What browser are you using ? If you still have users on IE8 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility) use a for loop.